# The data property is already declared as a prop

Tags: vue.js

Could one kindly advise me what I am doing wrong in JavaScript file.

I am new to Vue.js so your help would be much appreciated

**Plotly.vue**

```html
<template src="../../views/plotlychartshtml/plotlycharts.html"></template>

<script>
    import BarChart from '@/assets/javascripts/plotlychartsBar'

     export default {
    components: {
      'vue-plotly': BarChart 
    }
  }
</script>
```

**plotlycharts.html**

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <vue-plotly></vue-plotly>
    </div>
</div>
```

**plotlychartsBar.js**

```js
import VuePlotly from '@statnett/vue-plotly'

export default {
  extends: VuePlotly,
  data() {
      return {
         datacollection: {
            data: [{ 
              x: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'], 
              y: [40, 20, 30, 50, 90, 10, 20, 40, 50, 70, 90, 100] ,
              name: 'Plotly',
              type: 'bar',
            }]
         },
         layout: {},
         options: {},
      }
   },
    mounted() {
      this.datacollection
   }
}
```

I am following this tutorial https://github.com/statnett/vue-plotly but having challenges getting my JS code right.

I get this error message but unsure how to resolve it:

> vue.esm.js?efeb:591 [Vue warn]: The data property "options" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.
>
> found in
>
> ```
> ---> <BarPlotly> at C:\Users\martinha\vue-plotly\src\Plotly.vue
>        <Plotlycharts> at src/components/vuePlotly/Plotlycharts.vue
>          <App> at src/App.vue
>            <Root>
> ```
>
> found in
>
> ```
> ---> <BarPlotly> at C:\Users\martinha\vue-plotly\src\Plotly.vue
>        <Plotlycharts> at src/components/vuePlotly/Plotlycharts.vue
>          <App> at src/App.vue
>            <Root>
> ```

Comment: Why are you extending the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your Component declaration in `plotlychartsBar.js` **extends** `VuePlotly` (which already declares `options` as a `prop`) instead of declaring it **within its child `components`**:

```js
export default {
  //extends: VuePlotly, <= incorrect
  components: {
    VuePlotly,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

This question came up in my search when I was having the same problem.

I was getting this error in Nuxt while using the `@nuxtjs/composition-api` module.

I was using `@nuxtjs/composition-api` in my component for the router. I was also using `createLocalVue` in my test that was calling `localVue.use(VueCompositionAPI )`.

It looks like, if you are using `@nuxtjs/composition-api` in your component, you don’t need to add `localVue.use(VueCompositionAPI )` to your test.